# Array of strings as function parameter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parameters

I have found online the following way to get the length of an array of strings in C++:

```
template <size_t array_length> int foo(string (&arr)[array_length])
{
    return array_length;
}
```

Now consider the following (nonsense) program, which uses the above function.

```
template <size_t array_length> bool canConstruct(string target, string (&wordBank)[array_length])
{
  int m = foo(wordBank);
  int n = target.size();
  for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  { 
      if(m<n){return (wordBank[i]=="a");}
  }
  return false;
}


int main() 
{
    string wordbank[6] = {"r","a","t","ge","t","u"};
    bool output;
    output = canConstruct("targets", wordbank);
    cout << output << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program runs, but I would like to know if there is an equivalent realization of the "canConstruct" function without the use of templates. The "array_length]" argument in this function is never used in this function, so should not be necessary?
But somehow this was the only way that I managed to implement these functions.

Comment: It is used in `foo`, but compiler can deduce it from the argument, so it doesn't require you to spell it out. Underneath, your call would look like this: `int m = foo<array_length>(wordBank);`

Comment: `array_length` *is* used, both for determining the value of `canConstruct`'s template argument, and for instantiating `foo`. You can't make it a non-template since array sizes must be known at compile time. (Well, you can, if you "just" implement one overload for each possible array size...)

Comment: you can use `std::array<std::string,array_length>`. Under the hood it will be more or less identical, but the *use* of `array_length` will be more explicit

Comment: This works as long as you have a fixed set of strings in your word bank at compile time.
If not you can always use `std::vector<std::string> wordBank` and  pass that vector by const& to your canConstruct. Side note : stop using `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) lets the caller pass contiguous memory without the callee knowing whether it comes from a C array, `std::vector`, etc. As suggested in the comments, in C++, `std::array` is preferable to a C array.

```
bool canConstruct(string target, std::span<string> wordBank)
{
    int m = wordBank.size();
    ...
}

int main()
{
    std::array<string, 6> wordbank{"r", "a", "t", "ge", "t", "u"};
    bool output = canConstruct("targets", wordbank);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The "array_length]" argument in this function is never used in this function, so should not be necessary?

Thats not right. C-arrays decay to pointers to first element when not passed by reference. To pass the array by reference you do need to *use* its size. The size of the array is part of its type. Also to call `int m = foo(wordBank);` you need `wordBank` to be an array, a `string[array_length]`, and again, the size of the array is part of that type.

If you want one function that can be called with arrays of different size then the easiest way is to make the function a template, because arrays of different size are of different type. If you want to call the same function with differently sized arrays you can use `std::vector`.

---

I suggest you to go through the exercise of replacing the raw c-arrays in your code with `std::array<std::string,array_length>`. It will not change much, you will still need templates to allow for different sizes. The "*use*" of `array_length` will be more explicit though.